# Prettier plugin in eslint

Tags: tailwind-css, eslint, prettier

I want to use this plugin https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss

Currently my prettier config is managed in eslint per https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier

I want to add the tailwind prettier plugin in my eslint. How do I do that?

Comment: Check out this article maybe: https://www.misha.wtf/blog/tailwind-eslint-prettier

Answer (score 1):

Create a `prettier.config.js` file in your root folder and add the following line:

`module.exports = { plugins: ['prettier-plugin-tailwindcss'], }`

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.eslintrc`

`{ "extends": ["plugin:tailwindcss/recommended"] }`

More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-tailwindcss